# TextArea MaxLength - Supported or Not Supported?

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, w3c

I was getting ready to add a jQuery plugin to support maxlength on textarea's and noticed that the MaxLength attribute is working natively on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Is this thanks to HTML5 or ? Does that means having a maxlength on textareas no longer requires a jQuery type plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [`maxlength` was added to `<textarea>` in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html), so that's why you're seeing the behavior in newer browsers.

Do you need a plugin? that depends...if you need to support older browsers, then yes.