# HTML5 textarea character limit attribute

Tags: forms, html, textarea, character-limit

Is there an HTML5 attribute to set the maximum amount of characters in a textarea or other form?
I want a yes/no answer not some other method using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, maxlength works still: http://jsfiddle.net/xhqsB/1/ (demo has textarea and input type of text)

Beware that it is fairly easy for the client to bypass these restrictions, so if you are submitting data to a form, have the server-side script check the length of the submitted data.

Comment: Do you know what browsers support that attribute?

Comment: I've tested in Firefox 4, Chrome, and Safari, and it works in all three

Comment: K, I just tested it in IE8, and it's not supported for the textarea only the input field is supported.

Comment: Good to know, I'm on a mac and don't have IE. Do you have access to IE9?

Comment: The best browser in my opinion is Google Chrome. It is fast and supports almost everything. I have looked at IE9 but have not downloaded it. The only reason I have IE8 is because I am a web-developer, and I use it for browser testing and more people use IE8 than IE9.

Comment: Also, I tested it in Firefox 3.6 It doesn't support the maxlength for textarea.

Comment: You said for HTML5 so why is IE8 important?

Answer (score 0):

see: [textarea – text input area - HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/textarea.html)

the `maxlength` attribute is new to HTML5 for `<textarea>` but has been available for `<input type="text" />` for a while

see other similar questions:

[jquery - TextArea MaxLength - Supported or Not Supported? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372413/textarea-maxlength-supported-or-not-supported)

[How to impose maxlength on textArea in HTML , Javascript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-javascript)