# characteres jquery count

Tags: jquery, validation

which good (small and easy to use) jquery plugin to control the amount of characters in textarea Can I use?

When you finish entering a character, if the maximum amount was exceeded the character should be deleted.

I should not be allowed to enter up to a certain number of characters (parameter), compatible with Internet Explorer 6.0 and work when you copy and paste text.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/jquery-count-characters-in-textarea

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the default `maxlength`? `<input type="text" maxlength="20" />`

Comment: And remember any client-side check for character length will need to be duplicated on the server. Never check just on the client.

Comment: sorry, textarea is my html tag.

Comment: @Utkanos I need to check on both sides.

Comment: @NikolaK. I saw it post but unfortunately does not help. I added more information to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do aggree with using the `maxlength` attribute.
But if you want to use a textarea too, you need to use a plugin.

(As far as I know maxlength doesn't work with textarea.)
Consider using the [jQuery validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)([Another site here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)):

```
$(function() {

$("#yourform").validate({
    rules: {
        theinputname: "therule"
    },
    messages: {
        theinputname: "iferror"
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need any javascript at all for that. just give the input a maxlength="somenumber". even if it is a text area. see my jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/XKxHq/

Comment: sorry, is textarea my html tag.

Comment: It doesn't work in Internet explorer 6.0. Only in new browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372413/textarea-maxlength-supported-or-not-supported